# Electrophilic or nucleophilic addition?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In this reaction: 
$$\ce{H2C=O + H2O -> H2C-(OH)2}$$
My textbook says it's a nucleophilic addition reaction.

But in this reaction:
$$\ce{H2C=CH2 + HBr -> H3C-CH2Br}$$
is an electrophilic addition reaction. 
How do we know when a reaction is via an electrophilic or nucleophilic addition?

Comment: Additon to aldehydes or ketones are always Nucleophilic. I have rarely seen any electrophilic addition to aldehydes or ketones. But addition to C=C , i.e. alkenes are mostly electrophilic.

Comment: I agree. The C=O bond is strongly polarised making the C receptive to nucleophiles

Comment: Why can't we say "making the O receptive to electrophiles ". @Waylander Please help me out and thank you so much for your time!

Comment: You can say that. There is a well-established procedure for making carbonyl groups more reactive by premixing them with Lewis acids e.g. BF3 before adding a nucleophile to attack the C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning organic chemistry is about learning key modes of reactivity and being about to identify key features of reactants that may trigger relevant modes.

Relevant examples here are:

1. Nature of orbitals: Carbonyl groups have a low lying $\sigma^{*}$ orbital that is quite susceptible to nucleophilic attack. Alkenes, on the other hand, do not. What alkenes do have is a lot of electron density, so they are susceptible to protonation to form cations.
2. Acidity. Water is very mildly acidic while hydrogen bromide is quite acidic. Therefore different modes of reactivity should be considered.

The real question here is: Why are you trying to compare these two reactions at all? They're using different reagents with very different functional groups. Naturally, very different mechanisms were involved between the two reactions.

Comment: I came across these two questions in my textbook and I just wasn't happy with the answer my teacher gave me. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

As Soumik Das correctly pointed out , "Additon to aldehydes or ketones are always Nucleophilic."

In your case , this can be viewed as ,

$$\ce{H2C=O}$$ has a carbon attached to oxygen , which is fairly *electronegative* . As a result , a partial positive $(\delta^+)$ charge gets created on the carbon.As a result , the lone pairs on the oxygen atom of $\ce{H2O}$ get attracted towards the slightly positive carbon and carries out *nucleophilic addition reaction*.

I hope you can carry it from here now.

Comment: So does a partial negative charge develop on the oxygen and could attract the H+ from the water molecule, making it an electrophilic addition reaction.

Comment: @raajsuriya it could definitely take place, but the step here which ultimately leads to the product formation of the more stable product is the nucleophilic addition.Please upvote and accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Both products are the same, aren't they? @Tanuj

Comment: I gave it an upvote alright but I can't accept the answer because it doesn't really help or answer my question. Thank you so much for your time though. @Tanuj

Comment: @raajsuriya both products are the same but the product is formed through a transition state which is more stable (in which activation energy is less) and that is nucleophilic addition and not eletrophilic addition.